# Azure "/_partitionKey"

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I created multiple collections through code without realising the importance of having a partition key. I have since read the only way to add a partition key and redistribute the data is by deleting the collection and recreating it.

I don't really want to have to do this as I have quite a-lot of data already and want to avoid the downtime. When I look the Scale & Settings menu in Azure for each of my collections is see this below.

[image]

Can someone explain this - I thought my partition key was null but looks like MS have given me one called `_partitionKey`? Can I not just add `_partitionKey` to my documents, run a script to update them all to the key I want to use (e.g country)?

Comment: i'm not sure i understand your question correctly, but you cannot change the partition key, if you want to update the documents with the partition key - you can do that, but you cannot change it (the name of the partition key). you can change the value on the document for the partition key as well

Comment: So _partitionKey is my partition key? None of my documents have this object in the json. If I add "_partitionKey": "France" to my document will this be used as a partition key?

Comment: @Starchand yes, it should override `_partitionKey` set by Azure (which I presume is either just `null` or `undefined`). By default, if you don't define a PK then Azure will just allocate any documents to a `null` partition which of course isn't scalable.

Comment: @James ah, perfect! Thanks

Comment: @James...It won't. You can't change the partition key value. Document needs to be deleted and recreated in order to change the partition key.

Comment: @GauravMantri so old documents will be partitioned as null/undefined. Any new documents created with "_partitionKey": "country" will get partitioned correctly?

Comment: @GauravMantri sorry I was referring to new documents if the OP sets the `_partitionKey`, I should've explained that more clearly. However, having said that, if you need to edit documents anyway then removing / re-adding shouldn't be any more complicated, just need to be wary of the volume and the current RU/s set.

Comment: @Starchand yeah new documents will partition correctly, existing documents have already been physically stored and therefore would need to be removed & re-added to be moved into the correct physical partition.

Answer (score 3):

This is a new feature which allows non-partitioned collections (now called containers in the latest SDKs) to start using partitions with 0 downtime. The big caveat is that you need to be using the latest SDKs (which will be announced GA **really** soon (in fact most are already published, just waiting on doc publishing/etc.). Portal got the feature first since it's using the latest SDK under the covers already.